# What does the vertical bar in "q|p − 1" mean?

Tags: c#, math, cryptography

In the paper [*An Efficient Certificateless Encryption for Secure
Data Sharing in Public Clouds*](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1621&context=ccpubs), section 2.3 says:

> KGC takes as input a security parameter *k* to generate two primes *p* and *q* such that *q*|*p* − 1.

What does *q*|*p* − 1 mean? Is it *q* = 1 − *p*? I want to ask for clarification because the code I've written is only generating two random large prime numbers:

```
Random rand = new Random();
BigInteger p = BigInteger.genPseudoPrime(128, 10, rand);
Random rand2 = new Random();
BigInteger q = BigInteger.genPseudoPrime(128, 10, rand2);
do{ q = BigInteger.genPseudoPrime(128, 10, rand2); }
while (p == q);
```

Is this acceptable? If not, how should I write the code?

Edited:
May I know how should I write the code? Is it ok to like generate p, generate q, if p=q, regenerate it, and then if (p-1) % q /= 0 , regenerate q or something? or what would be the better way?

Thanks!

Comment: The `|` operator is [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR), I am unsure about the rest.

Comment: [In mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Mathematics), *a* ∣ *b* means *a* divides *b* (i.e., *a* is a factor of *b*, or *b* is a whole multiple of *a*).

Comment: @MichaelLiu I was pretty sure mathematics used `/` for that in one-line expressions (when not using `÷`)

Comment: I am not sure that is what the formula wants. Please provide a link to the specification you are trying to follow, I think something is getting lost between the specification and your question.

Comment: @Draco18s: They're different. *a* / *b* is an **operation** that means *a* divided by *b*. *a* | *b* states a **fact**, that *a* is divisible into *b*.

Comment: it is from this paper

http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1621&context=ccpubs

page 5/14

Comment: @MichaelLiu Ahhh, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, the [vertical bar “|”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Mathematics) is a mathematical symbol that represents **divisibility** (not to be confused with the **division operator** “/”). The expression *a* | *b* (which is read aloud as "*a* divides *b*" or "*a* is a factor of *b*") means that *a* is a divisor of *b*. Thus, *q* | *p* − 1 means that *q* must evenly divide *p* − 1. Equivalently, *p* and *q* must satisfy the condition (*p* − 1)/*q* = *k* for some integer *k*.

Comment: or in C# terms `(p-1) % q == 0`

Comment: is it (p-1) % q == 0 or q %(p-1)? I think I'm confused here.

Comment: @Hitsugaya: It's the first one.

Comment: ok...cheers! May I know how should I edit the code? Is it ok to like generate p, generate q, if p=q, regenerate it, and then if (p-1) % q /= 0 , regenerate q or something? or what would be the best way?

Comment: You would have to ask a number theory or cryptography expert. But I suspect that repeatedly generating two random primes until that condition is satisfied will take forever.

Comment: Given that you want them to divide by *k*: randomly generate two large primes *q* and *k*, then multiply them to get *p*.

Comment: bt if so, p would not be a prime anymore, no?